# Error in running boottest in R after feols

Tags: r

I'm encountering this issue while running feols in R. I run the following code

`r1 <- feols(log_pop ~ interaction_dday_n.[2:21]+ interaction_dday_.[0:321] | regionID + wkofyr + month + dayofwk + year + holiday + hour, sample)`

```
set.seed(1234)
dqrng::dqset.seed(1234)
boottest(r1, clustid="regionID", param = "interaction_dday_n8", B=999, bootcluster="regionID")
```

I can run feols without any issue. However, when I run boottest, I got the following error

> NOTE: 1 observation removed because of NA values (LHS: 1).
> Error in feols(fml = log_pop ~ 1 | regionID + wkofyr + month + dayofwk +  :
> Argument 'data' must be either: i) a matrix, or ii) a data.frame. Problem: it is not a matrix nor a
> data.frame (instead it is a function).

I checked my dataset "sample" and it's definitely a data frame. Could you please assist me? Thank you

I tried to use replace "r1" with "update(r1)" as instructed in one thread that encountered an issue with feols and same error. However, it did not resolve my issue.